# how to define type variable to call generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics

Have a generic method shown below, wants to call the method with a variable which is the matching type. How to define such variable? and how to assign the type to it.

no problem calling it with C1 and C2

```
t.<C1> getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);   
t.<C2> getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);
```

how to define a variable to call the generics method?

how to do something like this in Java

```
Type <? extends JsonXformIntf> theType = C1.getType();
t.<theType> getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);

theType = C2.getType();
t.<theType> getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);
```

Comment: What do you think you'll gain from doing this? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Generics are erased in Java so ... you can't do that. Maybe if you told us why you think you need this we can help.

Comment: @Radiodef what do you mean `Generics are erased in Java`?

Comment: [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So you can't obtain a type like a variable.

Comment: But the point is I don't understand why you think you need this because *"no problem calling it with C1 and C2"*. So you should edit your question and describe it in more detail.

Comment: Type erasure is only half of the truth: http://gafter.blogspot.de/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Comment: @zapl But I don't see how that is relevant here since it's mainly an introspective trick.

Comment: @Radiodef I don't know because I don't even understand the question. However `Type theType` reminded me a lot of type tokens and they are used whenever you do need type information that would normally be erased.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that they both compile, there is absolutely no difference between these two in terms of the compiled bytecode (and thus no possible difference in runtime behavior):

```
t.<C1>getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);   
t.<C2>getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);
```

Generics is compile-time only. After type erasure, they are both `t.getListConfigObjects("foo", String.class);`. In other words, the type argument you specify *is not known to the method at runtime*.

The only use of an explicitly-specified type argument is for the compiler's type-checking purposes -- explicitly specifying a right type argument will allow the compiler to compile it (whereas the compiler may otherwise infer it wrong); conversely, explicitly specifying a wrong type argument will make it not compile. However, if they both compile, then there is no difference.

Therefore, it wouldn't make sense to specify a type argument that is not known at compile-time, because compile-time is the only time when such a type argument is used at all. Simply pick any type argument that allows it to compile.